# running a java code using Jar file on Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I have a question. I want to run a java code on a Hadoop system. Based on admin instruction, I should create a Jar file and then run a bash code to submit my job. Based on my knowledge of programming, each code must have a main class but I read from other sources that in Hadoop maybe we have different story. The question is that should I have a main class and then create a Jar file or it is possible to submit my Jar file without main class? Since I'm building the code using ant, I can create Jar file without main class. Sorry It is the first time that I want to run a job on hadoop cluster and I am totoally confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The story is same here as well. Write your Hadoop job with main and create the jar which includes all the required resources. Copy it to your cluster and run using `bin/hadoop jar` command. For example:

```
hadoop jar abc.jar YourMainClass
```

BTW, what have you heard?